# Problem connecting to OneDrive File Picker v8

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to integrate the [OneDrive File Picker v8 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/?view=odsp-graph-online) into a SPA project but I keep getting an error in connecting to the picker which I can't decipher.

[Here's what the error from the popup window of the picker looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU1XL.png)

I'm following the provided [Javascript basic consumer sample](https://github.com/OneDrive/samples/tree/master/samples/file-picking/javascript-basic-consumer) to get things started but I'm having no luck so far, configuring the sample app like in the code block below with both the provided Azure Client ID and a personal Azure Client ID [I set up following the Picker docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/?view=odsp-graph-online#required-setup) still results in the same issue as the image above.

```
// 'javascript-basic-consumer/scripts/auth.js'
const msalParams = {
    auth: {
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers",
        clientId: {"2ab80a1e-7300-4cb1-beac-c38c730e8b7f" or "my-client-id"},
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000"
    },
}
```

Scrolling through the dev console for the picker I see the following error:

```
plt.odsp-common.js:1 GraphError: ObjectHandle is Invalid
    at t.a (res-1.cdn.office.net/files/odsp-web-prod_2023-10-27.002/odcfilepickerwebpack.manifest/plt.odsp-common.js:1:286129)
    at t [as constructor] (res-1.cdn.office.net/files/odsp-web-prod_2023-10-27.002/odcfilepickerwebpack.manifest/plt.odsp-common.js:1:24023)
    at new t (res-1.cdn.office.net/files/odsp-web-prod_2023-10-27.002/odcfilepickerwebpack.manifest/plt.odsp-common.js:1:62054)
    at res-1.cdn.office.net/files/odsp-web-prod_2023-10-27.002/odcfilepickerwebpack.manifest/plt.odsp-common.js:1:249215
    at e.then (res-1.cdn.office.net/files/odsp-web-prod_2023-10-27.002/odcfilepickerwebpack.manifest/plt.odsp-common.js:1:90280)
    at res-1.cdn.office.net/files/odsp-web-prod_2023-10-27.002/odcfilepickerwebpack.manifest/plt.odsp-common.js:1:248860
    at Object.A [as _notify] (res-1.cdn.office.net/files/odsp-web-prod_2023-10-27.002/odcfilepickerwebpack.manifest/plt.odsp-common.js:1:86424)
    at Object.enter (res-1.cdn.office.net/files/odsp-web-prod_2023-10-27.002/odcfilepickerwebpack.manifest/plt.odsp-common.js:1:88881)
    at e._run (res-1.cdn.office.net/files/odsp-web-prod_2023-10-27.002/odcfilepickerwebpack.manifest/plt.odsp-common.js:1:94087)
    at e._error (res-1.cdn.office.net/files/odsp-web-prod_2023-10-27.002/odcfilepickerwebpack.manifest/plt.odsp-common.js:1:93595)
```

and I see that the picker is making API calls to an `unauth` route like `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drives/unauth/items/root?{queryParams}` even though the `Authorization` headers are provided correctly.

And the weirdest part is that I know the provided sample code works correctly as I have managed to get it working previously, this issue only recently showed up as I was revisiting the code.

I would appreciate if someone with more knowledge about how the OneDrive file picker works could provide some insight on just what is going on with my issue.

Comment: I'm running into this as well, I suspect this Github issue is related.
https://github.com/OneDrive/samples/issues/61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue lies in the cid value being passed to the picker not being valid.

Try including 'cid' in the parameters when opening the picker.

Like this

```
const queryString = new URLSearchParams({
  filePicker: JSON.stringify(params),
  cid: 'CID VALUE',
});
const url = `${baseUrl}?${queryString}`;
```

[The cid value seems to came from oid of id tokens.](https://github.com/OneDrive/samples/issues/61#issuecomment-1814545188)

It's formatted as a uuid, but just remove the dashes and only use the last half of the string. Eg: idTokenClaims.oid.replace(/-/g, "").slice(16).

As you know, originally, this value was not required to be set by the developer. it seems there might be an issue on the v8 SDK side.